# how to align the table layout in android

Tags: android-layout

i am developing some web service based android application ...i want to show below type table view in my application..how can i do?

dynamic table layout code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                        final LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(
                                FifthActivity.this);
                        MainLayout.setWeightSum(1.0f);
                        TableRow row1 = new TableRow(FifthActivity.this);
                        row1.setId(1000 + sCount);
                        TextView text1 = new TextView(FifthActivity.this);
                        text1.setText(button.getText());
                        final Button button = new Button(FifthActivity.this);
                        EditText e = new EditText(FifthActivity.this);

                        e.setWidth(20);
                        e.setHeight(20);
                        button.setText(" X ");
                        button.setWidth(20);
                        button.setHeight(20);
                        button.setId(2000 + sCount);
                        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                MainLayout.removeView(findViewById(v
                                        .getId() - 1000));
                            }
                        });

                        sCount++;
                        row1.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 0.25f));      
                        row1.addView(text1);
                        row1.addView(e);
                        row1.addView(button);
                        MainLayout.addView(row1);

                    }
                    ll.addView(MainLayout);
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

here's output

[image]

how can i align this table column as view format....pls any one help me....
thank in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to call `setWeightSum()` on your parents.

What is the type of your **MainLayout** ?

I guess its not a **TableLayout** since table rows in **TableLayout** get aligned automatically.

So making your `MainLayout` a `TableLayout` should do what you want.

see the TableLayout documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Comment: here's coding... 
final TableLayout MainLayout = new TableLayout(FifthActivity.this);